# MySQL throws an error but still executes the query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to execute this query in MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO eier_borettslag(bsID, eierID)
VALUES(1, 1);
```

MySQL prompts me with this error message:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Could someone help me identify the syntax error and explain why the query gets executed even though the syntax is wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "in MySQL"? What program are you using?

Comment: I am trying to execute the query in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Do you have any triggers on eier_borettslag

Comment: *the right syntax to use near ''* usually means the problem is at the end of the query. There is no problem at the end of your query. Try removing the semicolon. It is a separator but there is no other query after it. It could be the reason of the error message.

Comment: @axiac That worked, thanks!